# Where can I find a list of all possible messages that an XmlException can contain?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlexception

I'm writing an XML code editor and I want to display syntax errors in the user interface. Because my code editor is strongly constrained to a particular problem domain and audience, I want to rewrite certain XMLException messages to be more meaningful for users. For instance, an exception message like this:

> '"' is an unexpected token. The
>   expected token is '='. Line 30,
>   position 35

.. is very technical and not very informative to my audience. Instead, I'd like to rewrite it and other messages to something else. For completeness' sake that means I need to build up a dictionary of existing messages mapped to the new message I would like to display instead. To accomplish that I'm going to need a list of all possible messages XMLException can contain.

Is there such a list somewhere? Or can I find out the possible messages through inspection of objects in C#?

---

Edit: specifically, I am using XmlDocument.LoadXml to parse a string into an XmlDocument, and that method throws an XmlException when there are syntax errors. So specifically, my question is where I can find a list of messages applied to XmlException by XmlDocument.LoadXml. The discussion about there potentially being a limitless variation of actual strings in the Message property of XmlException is moot.

Edit 2: More specifically, I'm **not looking for advice** as to whether I should be attempting this; I'm just looking for any clues to a way to obtain the various messages. Ben's answer is a step in the right direction. Does anyone know of another way?

Comment: The Message attribute in XmlException can also be internationalized which further complicates the issue as there is one message for each language for each exception type.

Answer (score 2):

Technically there is no such thing, any class that throws an XmlException can set the message to any string.  Really it depends on which classes you are using, and how they handle exceptions.  It is perfectly possible you may be using a class that includes context specific information in the message, e.g. info about some xml node or attribute that is malformed.  In that case the number of unqiue message strings could be infinite depending on the XML that was being processed.  It is equally possible that a particular class does not work in this way and has a finite number of messages that occur under specific circumstances.  Perhaps a better aproach would be to use try/catch blocks in specific parts of your code, where you understand the processing that is taking place and provide more generic error messages based on what is happening.  E.g. in your example you could simply look at the line and character number and produce an error along the lines of "Error processing xml file LineX CharacterY" or even something as general as "error processing file".

Edit:

Further to your edit i think you will have trouble doing what you require.  Essentially you are trying to change a text string to another text string based on certain keywords that may be in the string.  This is likely to be messy and inconsistent.  If you really want to do it i would advise using something like Redgate .net Reflector to reflect out the loadXML method and dig through the code to see how it handles different kinds of syntax errors in the XML and what kind of messages it generates based on what kind of errors it finds.  This is likely to be time consuming and dificult.  If you want to hide the technical errors but still provide useful info to the user then i would still recomend ignoring the error message and simply pointing the user to the location of the problem in the file.

Comment: Thanks for the reflector tip, I'll look into it.

Answer (score -1):

Just my opinion, but ... spelunking the error messages and altering them before displaying them to the user seems like a really misguided idea.

First, The messages are different for each international language.  Even if you *could* collect them for English, and you're willing to pay the cost, they'll be different for other languages.

Second, even if you are dealing with a single language, there's no way to be sure that an external package hasn't injected a novel XmlException into the scope of LoadXml.

Last, the list of messages is not stable.  It may change from release to release.

A better idea is to just emit an appropriate message from your own app, and optionally display -- maybe upon demand -- the original error message contained in the XmlException.

Comment: Languages aren't a problem in this scenario. It's a hosted environment where I control what language is used in exceptions. Given that I control the environment, I also know there are no external factors that could influence the content of exception messages in my code. Finally, if the language changes in a new release, which probably won't happen often, I will update the map to translate the new exception correctly.